# SIBER package in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, ellipse

I am trying to understand some example code from the `SIBER` package, but I'm lost.

I think this is about the IC of estimated bayesian ellipses:

```r
library(SIBER)

SEA.B <- siberEllipses(ellipses.posterior)

SEA.B.credibles <- lapply(as.data.frame(SEA.B),
                          function(x,...){tmp<-hdrcde::hdr(x)$hdr},
                          prob = cr.p)

print(SEA.B.credibles)
```

But, what about this one? This results in higher values than the SEA.b intervals:

```r
bayes.overlap.G2.G3 <- bayesianOverlap("1.3", "1.4",
    ellipses.posterior,
    draws = 10,
    p.interval = 0.95,
    n = 360)

print(bayes.overlap.G2.G3)

overlap.credibles <- lapply(
    as.data.frame(bayes.overlap.G2.G3),
    function(x,...){tmp<-hdrcde::hdr(x)$hdr},
    prob = cr.p)

print(overlap.credibles)
```

Why they are different areas/values? I know I missed something very crucial to understand.

Can somebody help me?